# How can I initialize an empty Buffer in C language

Tags: c, buffer

I'm doing a work in wish I have to read caracters from a File, and save them in a buffer. Later i have to output them, but for know I'm still struggling with the buffer thing.
I would like to know how can I initialize the buffer(empty of course) and then put caracters into that buffer.
I want to do it in another function who is called by int main(..).Here's waht I have:

```
buffer_t initBuffer(void) {
    // Reserves space for the buffer, ends program if it cant reserve     space.

    buffer_t buffer = malloc(sizeof(*buffer)); 
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating bufefr\n");
        exit(1);
    }
```

after this, how can I initialize it with his counter at 0?

---

Definition of `buffer_t`:

```
typedef struct buffer_s *buffer_t;

struct buffer_s {
    unsigned char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    counter;
}
```

Comment: Use `calloc` if you need to initialize it to zeros, but if you are going to store characters from a file in this buffer, you don't need to initialize it.

Comment: What *is* `buffer_t`? Is it a pointer to some structure? Something else?

Comment: I want at least to say that the counter is 0 se I can use it to add chars to it right?

Comment: buffer_t is a pointer to the structure of the type buffer_s
// typedef struct buffer_s *buffer_t;
i need also to define the structure buffer_s.
struct buffer_s {
unsigned char buffer[BUF_SIZE];   
counter;

}

Comment: @FranciscoOliveira , Yes. You can. Initialization isn't necessary. If you want to print the scanned buffer with `%s`, you should NUL-terminated the buffer if you've scanned character by character.

Comment: The thing is then I have to print it using the function fwrite of the C library, witch I also don't know how to do it... :(

Comment: The answer from Sourav are two ways, a third is to manually initialize the structure members one by one.

Comment: @CoolGuy - There **are** times when initializing the buffer before reading data from a file into it matters. In cases where the underlying file system and physical devices can return a lot of data really fast, data can arrive faster than the kernel's memory manager can map new physical pages to put the data into.  If you're reading data that fast, `calloc()` can be good because it often optimizes creating and setting the page(s).  If you're not reading data that fast, the `calloc()` doesn't matter because it doesn't take long enough compared to the time spent doing the actual IO.

Answer (score 1):

There are two apprroaches for two different needs. Choose whichever suits your requirement.

- If you want to initialize your allocated memory area to `0`, you can use [`calloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc) to directly do that (allocate and initialize to `0`).
- If you want to initialize your *allocated* buffer to some other value, you can use [`memset()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset) after doing a `malloc()`.